# Any studies on ear training, or musicality out there

Tags: harmony, ear-training, musicology, education

Are there any established and scientifically backed-up facts about what is possible, and what time it takes for ear training? Any studies out there that look at these questions? Like letting people learn intervals and evaluate their progress?

Background: Since almost one year I am doing ear training on a regular basis, approximately 20-30min every day. But my improvement is very slow. I saw people hearing a song and able to figure the harmony and melody out almost instantly, and ultimately thats my goal too.

So, I ask myself, if I continue will I ever, and when will I, reach this goal. Now by any objective measure I am still really far away. My slow progress makes it difficult for me to evaluate myself and having a realistic prospect on my own progress? So, I am looking what science has to say about it.

Comment: It's hardly scientific, and some people can grasp a lot of it almost immediately, whilst others never quite get there. So you'll come somewhere between. Not a lot of help to you, but an impossibly question to answer, objectively or subjectively (certainly the latter).

Comment: @Tim Yes, that's a "problem" and scientists have to find clever ways to deal with it. There are other examples with similar problems, for example learning experiments, or how to evaluate different learning paradigms for education, or when you want to find out why people do something (for example psychologist have come to the conclusion that instrospection, i.e. asking people about their motives, is not a good way to study something).  So, despite all these individual differences and difficulties have people come up with ways do operationlize it, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operationalization

Comment: @Tim Even the fact that some people seem to grasp it more easily should arose much scientifc interest in it, see the classic https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nature_versus_nurture debate

Comment: My points are progress rates will differ considerably person to person, as with everything - even growing up! And thus, 'how long will it take?' is impossible to answer - except ' between two and thirty years, as a rough estimate, which is not helpful. That apart, after 60+ yrs studying, *I'm* still learning, so where would the goalposts be anyway?

Comment: There is some scientific study of *amusia* which may be either congenital (present since birth) or acquired through brain damage, etc. But "science" probably isn't interested in your personal progress as an individual, as opposed to using this as one of many ways to understand how the brain works - and no effective treatments are known for the disorder. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amusia.

Comment: As for personal anecdotes, my own experience probably isn't at all helpful to others, since I can't remember a time when I *couldn't* do this. Of course I can remember learning how to *write down* what I was hearing, but knowing *how* to write something is a fairly trivial task compared with knowing *what* to write (for me, at least)

Comment: There might be such studies but how would that help you?  Unless you suspect you have some sort of musical learning disability (which is possible).  Everyone's different and some things come easy other slowly.  My question to you is are you doing this alone or with an instructor or partner?  Are you playing the notes, intervals, etc you are trying to identify or are you using a tape/cd, or s/w?  This matters a lot.  There are some good resources out there, CD and book Ear Training For Guitarists, Ear Master s/w, Band in a Box has an ear training video game.

Comment: @ggcg I am using the program "Functional ear trainer" and also software for interval recognition. Occasionaly I try to play songs by ear, I can find  fitting notes (something like basic improvising), but overall I often do not find out the right chords.

Comment: @StefanH, well then it sounds like you're making progress.  You be hard on yourself.  Chords contain a lot of intervals and are hence difficult to distinguish.  This is made worse by the presence of other instruments.  Transcribing a multi track recording by ear is not easy (I've been paid to do this long ago), the ear can be deceived by the multiple sources of sound.  There are also (1) non-linearity in the ear that creates new sounds not present in the acoustic field and (2) brain function such as fundamental tracking that can deceive one into perceiving a low tone that isn't there.

Comment: @StefanH, if you miss the chords are you at least in the key?

Comment: @ggcg I give you an example what I tried today, I heard the song "Adore" by Amy Shark in the radio (you can find it on youtube) and tried myself. I found out on the low A-string of my guitar the notes F-Bb-Cis in the verse fitted somehow, especially Bb and Cis sounded quite right, but for the F I became unsure, as if I played the whole chord it does not fitted, and even when I played the F an octave lower (on the E-string) it started sounding false. As I was not able to find out the real one I looked it up, and actually it goes Cis-f minor-Fis. Does it say anything about my (dis)ability?

Comment: @StefanH What is Cis-f minor-Fis?

Comment: @ggcg The chord progression c# major, then f minor, then f# major, the last one two measures. Similar when I write F-Bb-Cis I mean the notes f, Bb, c#.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, I found ["Aural Skills Acquisition"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0195117859) pretty interesting, and I think it might have references to relevant research.  It's a textbook and kinda expensive (I got it through interlibrary loan), and it's not an ear training book, it's a "here's what we know about teaching people ear training" book.

Just from an anecdotal point of view: for me it's definitely a marathon, not a sprint.  There are a ton of tiny little sub-skills to learn along the way.  And every time I get to one level I find there's always something more to learn.  Also, I've always found it most satisfying to combine drills with more practical exercises.  (E.g. if there's a song you want to learn from a recording--just go for it, don't wait till you've finished some ear training course.  It will be slow and take lots of trial and error and the results won't be perfect at first, but you'll learn a lot by trying.)

You might get better answers if you could ask more specifically about something you're trying to do and having trouble with.

"I saw people hearing a song and able to figure the harmony and melody out almost instantly": I'd bet they've been working on this for many years, consciously or not.  And if the song's in a genre they're familiar with, you may not realize the extent to which the song is assembled from common building blocks that they've played many times.